# OAuthException when I try to publish a news.reads action with OpenGraph

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I use facebook OpenGraph to send tickers in my Android application.

- when a user listen a music
- when a user read an article

I take the example from the facebook documentation to do this (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/open-graph)

My method works for the listen action but not for the read action.
I have an error when I try to post the read action (the article object is successfully added)

```
error: {HttpStatus: 500, errorCode: 1, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: An unknown error has occurred.}
```

I made the same application on iOS and both actions works.

Here is my method which send a listen action, for the read action I just replace "music.song" by "article" and "music.listens" by "news.reads":

```
 // Create a batch request
    RequestBatch requestBatch = new RequestBatch();

    // Set up the OpenGraphObject representing the book.
    OpenGraphObject song = OpenGraphObject.Factory.createForPost("music.song");
    song.setTitle(myMusicTitle);
    song.setDescription(myMusicDescription);

    // Set up the object request callback
    Request.Callback objectCallback = new Request.Callback() {

        @Override
        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
            // Log any response error
            FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
            if (error != null) {
              ...
            } else {
              ...
            }
        }
    };

    // Create the request for object creation
    Request objectRequest = Request.newPostOpenGraphObjectRequest(Session.getActiveSession(),
            song, objectCallback);

    // Set the batch name so you can refer to the result
       // in the follow-on publish action request
    objectRequest.setBatchEntryName("objectCreate");

    // Add the request to the batch
    requestBatch.add(objectRequest);


    // Request: Publish action request
    // --------------------------------------------
    OpenGraphAction readAction = OpenGraphAction.Factory.createForPost("music.listens");
    // Refer to the "id" in the result from the previous batch request
    readAction.setProperty("song", "{result=objectCreate:$.id}");

    // Set up the action request callback
    Request.Callback actionCallback = new Request.Callback() {

        @Override
        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
            FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
            if (error != null) {
               ...
            }
            else
            {
                String actionId = null;
                try {
                    JSONObject graphResponse = response
                            .getGraphObject()
                            .getInnerJSONObject();
                    actionId = graphResponse.getString("id");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    ...
                }
            }
        }
    };

// Create the publish action request
        Request actionRequest = Request.newPostOpenGraphActionRequest(Session.getActiveSession(),
                readAction, actionCallback);

// Add the request to the batch
        requestBatch.add(actionRequest);

// Execute the batch request
        requestBatch.executeAsync();
```

Does anybody know why I get this error ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: facebook sdk sucks ... that is the one true fact that i find out every time i have to work with this shit called facebook sdk for android